# Google Map is gray color

Tags: html, maps

my google maps script is gray when load the page, when I open the inspector of elements seen, I think it's for the resize, you can be? Thanks friends, I expect an answer. Here you have all the html of what would be the map, then this is included within a div. The strange thing is that when you resize the screen, is observed. I need help!!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

#googleMap {
 width: 100%;
height: 600px;
margin-top: 6.5%;
  overflow:visible;

 }
      img, embed, object, video {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
 }



 </style>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?      key=AIzaSyCbVI4cT8PjwlmV0pZfK961MGnd6H3aGoY&signed_in=false"> </script>

<script>

 var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(39.287649, -0.422548);
var myCenterverd=new google.maps.LatLng(39.287413, -0.422255);
var myCenterroig=new google.maps.LatLng(39.288497, -0.423953);
var myCentergroc=new google.maps.LatLng(39.287766, -0.421604);


 function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
   center:new google.maps.LatLng(39.287413, -0.422255),
   zoom:8,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
   //disableDefaultUI: true
    };
    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapOptions);

  //var marker=new google.maps.Marker({position:myCenter,icon:'gotaico.png'});
   var markerverd=new google.maps.Marker({position:myCenterverd,icon:'../dashboard/include/Mapa/iconosrellenos/gotaicoverd.png'});
   var markerroig=new google.maps.Marker({position:myCenterroig,icon:'../dashboard/include/Mapa/iconosrellenos/gotaicoroig.png'});
   var markergroc=new google.maps.Marker({position:myCentergroc,icon:'../dashboard/include/Mapa/iconosrellenos/gotaicogroc.png'});

   //marker.setMap(map);
  markerverd.setMap(map);
  markerroig.setMap(map);
  markergroc.setMap(map);
 }

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

 <body>
 <div id="googleMap"></div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Please post questions in English.

Comment: Ok, sorry, one fail.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the following styles are causing the error:

```
img,
embed,
object,
video {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

Remove these and it will work: https://jsfiddle.net/cug0an68/1/

Ps, you may want to set up a new api key as you have made this one publicly available